# Setting an array through a context in React

Tags: reactjs

So im trying to set an array on the context when a http request fails in a custom hook

Here is my hook:

```
const useHttp = (requestObj: any, setData: Function) => 
{
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false); 
    const ctx = useContext(GlobalContext);
        
    const sendRequest = useCallback(() =>
    {
        setIsLoading(true);
        
        fetch(requestObj.url, {
            method: requestObj.method ? requestObj.method: 'GET',
            headers: requestObj.headers ? requestObj.headers : {},
            body: requestObj.body ? JSON.stringify(requestObj.body) : null
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setIsLoading(false);
            setData(data);                
        })
        .catch(err => 
        {
            setIsLoading(false); 
            ctx.setErrors(
                (prevErrors: string[]) =>
                {
                    prevErrors.push(err.message)
                    return prevErrors;
                }
            );
            console.log('There was an error');
        });
    }, []);

    return {
        isLoading: isLoading,
        sendRequest: sendRequest
    }
}
```

Im setting the array using the previous state value.

but that doesnt seem to cause a redraw of the component that is using that state value.

```
const App: FC = () => {

    const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

    let modal = null

    if(errors.length > 0)
    {
        modal = ( 
            <Modal 
                heading="Warning" 
                content={<div>{errors}</div>}
                buttonList={
                    [
                        {label: "OK", clickHandler: ()=> {}, closesModal: true},
                        {label: "Cancel", clickHandler: ()=> {alert("cancelled")}, closesModal: false}
                    ]
                } 
                isOpen={true}/>
        )
    }

    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={{errors: errors, setErrors: setErrors}}>
            <ProviderV3 theme={defaultTheme}>
                <Toolbar></Toolbar>
                <Grid
                    margin='25px'
                    columns='50% 50%'
                    gap='10px'
                    maxWidth='100vw'>
                    <OwnerSearch />
                    <NewOwnerSearch />
                </Grid>
            </ProviderV3>
            {modal}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

When I debug the code I see the App class does not reevaluate when the state method setErrors is called from the hook. I see though if I just do a simple ctx.setErrors([err.message]) in the hook it does cause a reevaluation (though something else breaks). Why is the method using the previous state not working?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling `prevErrors.push()` try spreading the array.

```js
        ctx.setErrors(
          (prevErrors: string[]) => ([...prevErrors, err.message]),
        );
```

Comment: this is all done in typescript. when I try to use the spread operator I get: This syntax requires an imported helper named '__spreadArray' which does not exist in 'tslib'. Consider upgrading your version of 'tslib'. Though the spread operator seems to work for objects

Comment: Im using .map to copy the array and then adding the error to that and returning that.

Comment: That may work. I'm not sure why the spread gave you that error. I just spun up a new typescript app using create-react-app and I have no errors.

Comment: our config is custom so ill have to hunt down what was removed that is affecting this